# Rails collection_select with multiple and prompt options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently when I create a multi select the prompt option can be selected along with the other options. I would like to avoid the prompt being multi selected. Current code:

```
<%= collection_select(:vehicle_group ,:user_group_id, VehicleGroup.all, :id, :group_name, {:prompt => true}, {:multiple => true})%>
```

I have also tried include_blank with the same result being that "Please select" can be multi selected:

```
<%= collection_select(:vehicle_group ,:user_group_id, VehicleGroup.all, :id, :group_name, {:include_blank => "Please select"}, {:multiple => true})%>
```

Is there any way to avoid this?